# Convert text file from known (1252) encoding to UTF8 File

Tags: c#, file

I have a file which has text with windows-1252 encoding. How to convert it into UTF8 file format?

Comment: Strictly speaking ASCII is 7-bit only and as such is actually a subset of UTF8, but I assume since you mention code page 1252 that you have 8-bit characters from that code page. For details on converting those check out the [Encoding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Text.Encoding(v=vs.110).aspx) class.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError - I've removed that strange text from  the post. Should be more reasonable now.

Comment: Thanks Alex, Let me check this.

Answer (score 2):

The [Encoding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Text.Encoding(v=vs.110).aspx) class supports conversions.

```
byte[] asciiBytes = File.ReadAllBytes("C:\\ascii.txt");

Encoding ASCII_1252 = Encoding.GetEncoding("windows-1252");

byte[] utf8Bytes = Encoding.Convert(ASCII_1252, Encoding.UTF8, asciiBytes);

File.WriteAllBytes("C:\\utf8.txt", utf8Bytes);
```

Note that GetEncoding() relies on the underlying platform to support most code pages as explained here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t9a3kf7c(v=vs.100).aspx